# Прописные буквы в многословных названиях иностранных брендов/компаний

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, латиница-кириллица, транслитерация

Подскажите, если у нас есть название бренда/компании на латинице и оно пишется в несколько слов по правилам английского, то как его транслитерировать на русский, прописные буквы сохранятся во всех словах или только в первом? Например:

- General Motors — "Дженерал Моторс" / "Дженерал моторс";
- Rolls-Royce — "Роллс-Ройс" / "Роллс-ройс";
- Mitsubishi Group — "Митсубиси Груп" / "Митсубиси груп" и т. д.

"Грамота.ру" даёт рекомендацию по написанию составных названий брендов (**марок**) автомобилей, но неясно, распространяется ли это на названия **компаний** (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273123&v=full)):

> Неоднословные названия (марка и модель автомобиля), написанные кириллицей, пишутся через дефис, при этом все части наименования пишутся с прописной буквы: *«Лада-Приора»*, *«Тойота-Королла»*, *«Рено-Меган»*, *«Ниссан-Теана»*, *«Хёндай-Гетц»*, *«Ниссан-Альмера-Классик»*, *«Сузуки-Гранд-Витара»*. Но: *«Фольксваген-жук»* (перекличка с нарицательным существительным).

Также в одном из ответов "Грамота.ру" пишет только первое слово в названии компании с прописной, однако в подробности не вдаётся (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=204603)):

> Названия зарубежных фирм транскрибируют русскими буквами и заключают в кавычки. Поэтому корректно: *«Инглиш груп»*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопался и нашёл ответы и у Мильчина, и у Розенталя. Всё сводится к тому, что в названиях как отечественных компаний, так и транслитерируемых зарубежных с прописной пишут только первое слово и собственные имена. То есть верно:

- General Motors — "Дженерал моторс";
- Rolls-Royce — "Роллс-Ройс" (Роллс и Ройс — фамилии основателей
  компании, это имена собственные, поэтому также пишутся с прописной);
- Mitsubishi Group — "Митсубиси груп".

По [Мильчину](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091346.html#id-3%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-3155%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> **3.15.5. Названия зарубежных фирм, компаний, концернов, банков и т. п. из одного или нескольких слов**
> Их транскрибируют русскими буквами и заключают в кавычки. С прописной буквы в этих названиях пишут первое слово в кавычках и собственные имена. Напр.: *компании «Юнайтед стейтс стил»*, *«Дженерал моторс»*, *концерны «Пежо»*, *«Роллс-Ройс»*, *фирма «Сони»*, *компания «Кока-кола»*, *фирма «Юнайтед фрут компани»*, *банк «Морган Стэнли»*, *концерны «Фольксваген»*, *«Фиат»*.

По [Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=20):

> 9. В выделяемых кавычками названиях предприятий, фирм и т. п. первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы (родовое наименование и название, указывающее на профиль предприятия, пишутся со строчной буквы): *текстильный комбинат «Трёхгорная мануфактура»*, *завод «Красный Октябрь»*, *киноконцерн «Мосфильм»*, *акционерное общество «Московский вентиляторный завод»*, *шахта «Северная 2-бис»*, *концерн «Дженерал моторс корпорейшн»*, *фирма «Юнайтед фрут компани»*.